# Can a GPL binary, that has no source code released, be reverse engineered, and that source be released?

Tags: gpl, closed-source, binaries

can a GPL binary, that have no source code released, be reverse engineered and that source be released?

Some devs get a project in GPL, implement new things, release the binary but do not release the source code...

So, and if that binary that should have a source code, got reverse engineered? Is there any problem on creating a fork, still in GPL of couse, and releasing these sources for further development of anyone willing to help?

ps.: why ppl do that? They dont want to comply with gpl?

Comment: Could you take a look at [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/whats-to-prevent-a-user-from-reverse-engineering-a-gpl-program) and  tell us if it answers your question (except for the pps, which I fear we can't answer)?  If it doesn't otherwise satisfy you, could you let us know what remains unanswered by it?

Comment: @MadHatter the questioner context was about using gpl code in non gpl program, and that was out of scope to me. But both answers say that we can rev.eng. and release the source as gpl right? Now i see the answers work for me too, thx.

Comment: That was very much the basis on which I recommended the question, so I'm glad about that.  May I close this as a duplicate, since it told you what you wanted to know?  And I don't understand why people deliberately fail to comply with the GPL, either; it's very annoying.

Comment: Sure, this is a dup, not of the question but about the answers!

Comment: Have you considered contacting those authors (that are releasing GPL binaries without source code) and asking them directly, where is the corresponding source to be found? It could be an oversight that will be corrected if mentioned/asked.

Comment: @Brandin he was questioned explicitly why the last binary ,that fixed many bugs, had not the source code. He did just not answer... It felt like he wanted more likes or more donations... I think some ppl just dont understand what opensource means.

Comment: @VeganEye There's no conflict in getting donations. But if he expects extra payment for the source delivery itself, then that's only allowed under 6b, but normally that option would only apply to physical distribution (e.g. if you're distributing a physical product that contains GPL code). If you offered a binary online, then you need to offer "equivalent access" to the source (i.e. you can't charge more for the source than the binary). Most likely in this situation, he needs to deliver the source as specified in section 6d.